# SQLite Table-Level Encryption

Tags: ios, sqlite, encryption

We need to encryption in SQLite to secure our data from vulnerability. Is there any way of table-level encryption in SQLite? we tried to find out but we didn't yet get any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know about table level encryption but you can do DB level encryption using `SQLCipher`

Comment: thanks @Kuldeep I done with DB level encryption but our team wants specific table level encryption. Is it possible? if No then can you please share a link or anythings which specifically says that it can't done in SQLite so that i can convince them.

Comment: I don't know about table level encryption.

Comment: thanks @Kuldeep actually the problem is that they didn't mention about table-level encryption anywhere so if its not possible they need to mention that

Comment: I think native table encryption is a commercial option see extension `see` (sorry the duplicate)  https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite Encryption Extension [1] encrypts an entire database.
There is no option to encryption some tables and not others.  This is
because SEE operates at the pager layer and the pager does not know
what table a particular page belongs to.

But what you can do is separate your data into two separate database
files.  One file is encrypted and the other is not.  Then open your
database connection on the unencrypted file and ATTACH the encrypted
file, or vice versa.  SQLite does allow connections where there are
multiple attached databases, some of which are encrypted and others
not.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting `SQLite` database can easily be done using Pager. Table level encryption is not possible. If you are interested in details please write a message. I am working on a solution to be published soon.

Comment: [link](http://www.iqx7.com/education/sqlite-encryption)
Online training + package with info and source code in C. This project is still in progress, but I hope to get some people interested. I  am still working on the website, so let me know your comments please.

Comment: There is a commercial version now available:
http://www.iqx7.com/products/sqlite-encryption